# Reformat long list in PyCharm to have one item per line

Tags: python, pycharm

When I do the code formatting in Pycharm it reformats the long lists in this manner:

```py
style1 = [
    'Email:', 'SSN:', 'Address:', 'Home Phone:',
    'Mobile Phone: ', 'DOB:', 'Date of Surgery:',
    'Date of Service:', 'Facility of Service:', 'Clinic Number:',
    'Employer:', 'Work Phone: ', 'Fax: ', 'Type:', 'IPA:',
    'Health Plan:', 'ID #:', 'Claims Address:', 'Group #:',
    'Claim # / PO #:', 'Phone:', 'Fax:', 'Contact',
    'Adjuster Email', 'Util Review Phone', 'Util Review Fax',
    'Doctor:', 'NPI #: ', 'Date of Injury: ', 'Body Parts:',
    'Body Part Side:', 'Gender:', 'Diagnosis:', 'Diagnosis 2:',
    'Procedure:'
    ]
```

Is there any way to reformat in PyCharm and have one item per line, like so:

```py
style2 = [
    'Email:',
    'SSN:',
    'Address:',
    'Home Phone:',
    'Mobile Phone: ',
    'DOB:',
    'Date of Surgery:',
    'Date of Service:',
    'Facility of Service:',
    'Clinic Number:',
    'Employer:',
    'Work Phone: ',
    'Fax: ',
    'Type:',
    'IPA:',
    'Health Plan:',
    'ID #:',
    'Claims Address:',
    'Group #:',
    'Claim # / PO #:',
    'Phone:',
    'Fax:',
    'Contact',
    'Adjuster Email',
    'Util Review Phone',
    'Util Review Fax',
    'Doctor:',
    'NPI #: ',
    'Date of Injury: ',
    'Body Parts:',
    'Body Part Side:',
    'Gender:',
    'Diagnosis:',
    'Diagnosis 2:',
    'Procedure:'
    ]
```

I was trying to do it with .editconfig, but have not found a parameter that does the trick yet.

Comment: I'd just select the block, and find-and-replace `', '` with `',\n'` (with regexp mode enabled), then reformat again to fix the indentation.

Comment: (Alternately, you could use Black or `ruff format`; it'd format the list in a similar way.)

Comment: PyCharm [natively supports](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html#pycharm-intellij-idea) using [black](https://github.com/psf/black) for code formatting. Using a standard format instead of a personal style is usually recommended. Black would format this list with one entry per line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any shortcut to add '>>>' in front of lines in the docstring for doctest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793964/any-shortcut-to-add-in-front-of-lines-in-the-docstring-for-doctest)

Comment: Use the suggestion from AKX, there are many questions about using find&replace...